# Jasperserver Job

Tags: jasperserver

does anybody know in whitch Java class Job schedule and execution takes place?

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Jasperserver uses the Quartz scheduler libraries. Off the top of my head the settings XML files can be found in tomcat/webapps/Jasperserver/WEB-INF